# C - Using spaces in sscanf()

Tags: c, scanf, ansi-c

Im trying to parse an input string in the format `x y z` (spaces included) so that it will exit the loop when the entered string is valid. However, when I run this code, it outputs "incorrect format" 3 times and each time, `valid = 1`. Is there any other way to get this to work without having to parse it manually?

```
int valid = 0, x, y, z;
char str[20];
while (valid != 3) {
  scanf("%s", str);
  valid = sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
  if (valid != 3) {
    printf("Incorrect format\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: The `%s` format specifier will only read up to the first *whitespace*. You simply want `if (scanf ("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z) != 3) { fprintf (stderr, "error: incorrect format.\n"); return 1; }` You don't need `str` you don't need `valid` and you don't need a `while` loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If the input is line-oriented then it is a good idea to read a whole line and then use `sscanf` on it.  For example your suggestion won't deal with the input string `123` followed by Enter , it will keep reading more lines

Comment: I agree whole heartedly, but with the loop and no example input it was ambiguous.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s", str);` should be: `if( 1 != scanf("%19s", str) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input line failed" ); }  // implied else, scanf successful`

Comment: this statement: `char str[20];` is not allowing near enough room.  Suggest something more like: `char str[50];`  And then the call to `scanf()` would be: `if( 1 != scanf("%49[^\n]", str) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input line failed" ); } // implied else, scanf successful`  Use `"%49[%\n]` because this will read all the way to a newline -or- 49 characters, which ever comes first.  The input specifier '%49s' will stop inputting at the first space.

Comment: A better option for reading a line would be to use either `get_s()`, `fgets()`, or `getline()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the primary stumbling block you create is to attempt a read with `scanf ("%s", str)`. The `%s` format specifier will only read characters up to the first whitespace encountered. If you enter 3-integers separated by a space, you will never read more than the first one into `str`. This makes it impossible to parse 3-integer values with `sscanf` from `str` that can contain no more than 1.

To correct the problem, either read 3-integer values directly with `scanf`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    
    int x, y, z;
    printf ("enter 3 integers: ");
    if (scanf ("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z) != 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("x : %d\ny : %d\nz : %d\n", x, y, z);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Or, the preferred way to handle *line-oriented* input is by using the *line-oriented* input functions `fgets` or POSIX `getline`. This will avoid the many pitfalls with taking user input with `scanf` that new C programmers routinely fall into. [**Never, never, never** use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/), it is so insecure it has been removed from the C11 library.

An equivalent example using `fgets` and `sscanf` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 128

int main (void) {
    
    int x, y, z;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    printf ("enter 3 integers (on a single line): ");
    if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z) != 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("x : %d\ny : %d\nz : %d\n", x, y, z);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

(it is the same for both)

```
$ ./bin/rd3int
enter 3 integers: 10 12 14
x : 10
y : 12
z : 14
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: 128 is certainly better than OP's 20, but I usually like an obnoxiously generous input buffer size, like `char buf[4096]`, to guard against the user falling asleep on the `z` key, or in this case playing bongos on the number keys and space bar ;)

Comment: Agreed. Here since we were looking at no more than 3 int values (max 10 chars each + 2 spaces) -- I just quadrupled it `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", str)` scans text until space occurs. So for input `1 2 3`, `str` is read 3 times, with content `1`, `2`, `3`.

Try using `gets(str)` instead.

Comment: Oh no. [Never ever use the unsafe, deprecated in C99 and eradicated from the Standard in C11, `gets()` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) Instead, use `fgets()` or the POSIX `getline()` function. You can even use the much-maligned `scanf()` more safely than `gets()`.